# How can I detect integer overflow in integer multiplication

Tags: java, math, try-catch, size

```java
int base, power, result = 1;   
for (int i = 1; i <= power; i++) {
    result *= base;
}
System.out.println(base + " to the power of " + power + " result: " + result);
```

10 to the power of 9 result: 1000000000
but;
10 to the power of 10 result: 1410065408

In my application this is logically an error but how can I detect this error before the println?
for instance, when this error occurs, I want to print
"result data type is int 32bit, it must not exceed 2,147,483,647"

How can I catch these kinds of errors?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.baeldung.com/java-overflow-underflow
I have found an enough answer here.
I have corrected my code like this:

```java
try {
    for (int i = 1; i <= power; i++) {
        result = Math.multiplyExact(base, result);
    }
} catch(ArithmeticException intSize) {
    base = result = 0;
    System.out.println("out of size int32: ")
}
```